# Copy local git repo with history of old commits to a new remote repo

Tags: git

In my local repo, I can see 10 commits using the command `git log`

I want to copy this state to a new empty remote repo for backup.

When I try `git push -u newRemote --all` it pushes the state of an old-remote repo and not the local repo.

I have just 1 commit in my old-remote repo and this is what is see in my newRemote after the push.

Please help.

**Update my .git/config file**

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "oldRemote"]
        url = git@bitbucket.org:kickbox/mp2.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/oldRemote/*
[remote "newRemote"]
        url = git@bitbucket.org:kickbox/newRemote.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/newRemote/*
```

Comment: what branches do you have and which one is checked out?

Comment: I have not created any new branches. master in the only branch in my remote repos.

Comment: What's the output of `git status` before to push ?

Comment: git status says no untracked files